# How do I get rid of zeros at the end of dollars format on JAVA?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting rid of the zero's after I compile my program. The program will come out like:
Enter the amount of pennies: 456 <--- whatever number the user enters
456 pennies equals 8.0 dollars and 76.0 cents. I've been having trouble getting rid of the .0 at the end fo dollars and having cents with no zero at the end as well so it shows up like:
Enter the amount of pennies: 456
456 pennies equals 8 dollars and 76 cents.

```
import.java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Blah

{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int pennies;
  double dollars;
  double cents=0;
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#");

  System.out.print("Enter the amount of pennies: ");

  pennies=input.nextInt();

  dollars = pennies/100 - cents;
  cents = pennies % 100;

  if(dollars<0)
         dollars = -dollars;

  System.out.println(pennies + "pennies equals " + dollars + "dollars and " + cents + " cents.");

   }
}
```

Comment: use Math.round(dollars)

Comment: Please edit the code block to include the close curly bracket and use consistent indention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a `DecimalFormat` so now its time to use it

```
System.out.println(pennies + " pennies equals " 
        + decimalFormat.format(dollars) + " dollars and " 
        + decimalFormat.format(cents) + " cents.");
```